# c# selenium chromedriver flash

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

How can i disable flash with Chrome 57 version? 
i'm using Chromedriver 2.28

i tried

```
options.AddArguments("--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash");
options.AddArguments("--disable-plugins-discovery");
```

But chrome using his own "Google Pepper"
It works if i manually enabled #prefer-html-over-flash option in "chrome://flags"
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGuZL.jpg)

But how can i make it with selenium chromedriver?

Answer (score 1):

Here is [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). You can try `--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash`(I haven't tried this) but there are bunch of commands available related to Flash.

Good Luck !!!

Mark +1 if this answer is useful to you.